# JointJS manhattan router has lines that are not vertical or horizontal

Tags: jointjs

I'm using links defined with the Manhattan router. According to the documentation, the lines should be vertical and horizontal, but for some of them they start or end oblique. I can't find how to fix them.

On the following picture, the red and green lines are correct, while the orange lines are not as expected.

The code is the same to draw all the lines. Here is the code for the orange lines:

```
var link = new joint.dia.Link({
source: {
    x: rects[item.StatusId].mOut.x,
    y: rects[item.StatusId].mOut.y
},
target: {
    x: rects[item.ModifyStatusId].mIn.x,
    y: rects[item.ModifyStatusId].mIn.y
},
router: {
    name: 'manhattan',
    args: {
        startDirections: ['top'],
        endDirections: ['right']
    }
},
attrs: {
    '.connection': { stroke: mColor, 'stroke-width': 3 },
    '.marker-target': { fill: mColor, stroke: mColor, d: 'M 10 0 L 0 5 L 10 10 z' }
}
```

});

links.push(link);

[image]

Comment: Hi, did you find a way to fix this perhaps?

Comment: my application does this as well.